# How to get correct colours when printing in a kiosk

Tags: printing, white-balance

Is there any way to get consistent (i.e. un-'corrected') prints from a photo printing kiosk?  I have tried to ask the people in the shops but they don't seem to be very knowledgeable about the equipment.

I spent some time editing my images in Photoshop to get the colour balance, saturation etc the way I wanted and then when I printed my images, they appeared different to how I had edited them.  As a case in point, I added a coloured border to some prints so that I could manually trim them down to a smaller size and this solid coloured border came out in several different shades - perhaps this coloured border even influenced the colour correction?  On a separate occasion, multiple prints of **the same image** came out differently.

Comment: Is your editing computer color corrected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then the printer in the kiosk has some "magic" turned on, and tries to auto-improve the images.

If you want color fidelity, you will have to use a color-managed environment (calibrate your monitor), embed the ICC info into your image, and find a place where you can print on a printer for which you yourself can create an ICC profile. (Printer default ICC is usually not enough, because who knows what ink they are using...)